# I'm trying to put basic LINQ query into simple mvc on asp.net core but where to put using (var context = new BloggingContext())

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

1.
I'm new in programming and very new in c# and asp.net core. Following this tutorial I got simple MVC project with linked "blogging" database. 
So, now my view index.cshtml file code is:

```
@model IEnumerable<EFGS.Models.Blog>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MealOperators";
}

<h2>Blogs</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-controller="MealOperators" asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Url</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BlogId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Now I want to learn how to get simple data(single entity) from database and show it in view (at my local page http://localhost:12345/blogs). 
For example, how to show what is Url of the blog with `BlogId=5`.
I found this example for the above purpose: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/basic.html#loading-a-single-entity

According to it, I have to use this statement:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = context.Blogs
        .Single(b => b.BlogId == 5);
}
```

But, sorry for my stupidity, I do not understand where to put it. If I put it in Index.cshtml i get:

> The type or namespace name 'BloggingContext' could not be found...

If I put something like:

```
@namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Models{}
```

or

```
@using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Models
```

or

```
@using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Controllers
```

I still get other errors.

Could you please give me some good links on good asp.net core templates/sourcecodes where I can find basic queries not partly like in link/example above, but inside whole project so that i can trace and understand what and where to put, what is linked and related with what.

2.
And, btw, where can I read and understand more deeply what is @model , Model and modelItem in the example above? I'm asking, because when I tried to make similar mvc project on my own, I always got

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

error and did not understand how should I fix it.
Thanks!

Update:
BlogsController:

```
using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Controllers
{
    public class BlogsController : Controller
    {
        private BloggingContext _context;

        public BlogsController(BloggingContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
              return View(_context.Blog.ToList());


            //using (var context = new BloggingContext())
            //{
            //    var blogs = from x in context.Blog select x;

            //    return View(blogs.ToArray());
            //}


        }

        private IActionResult View(Func<Blog[]> toArray)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Blog blog)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Blog.Add(blog);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(blog);
        }

    }
}
```

BloggingContext:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Models
{
    public partial class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
             : base(options)
        { }

        public BloggingContext()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Url).IsRequired();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Blog)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Post)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.BlogId);
            });
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blog { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Blogs.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Models
{
    public partial class Blog
    {
        public Blog()
        {
            Post = new HashSet<Post>();
        }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Promo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Post { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Update:

Startup.cs

```
    using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Models;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                Configuration = builder.Build();
            }

            public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;";
                services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

                string connectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
                services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));  
                services.AddMvc();
            }

            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
              loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                loggerFactory.AddDebug();

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    app.UseBrowserLink();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                }

                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can put that code in your action method, an external service class ( which will be called from your action method) etc.. It is up to you. You need to import the namespaces where these classes belong with a using statement in your file ( ex :`using System.Text'`). Please check http://www.asp.net/ for tutorials

Comment: Please note this kind of question is not suitable for SO: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: @Tseng , I have asked for a template, because some other answers on SO and https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/index.html have only partial answers that i do not understand, because i do not understand where to put partial examples. But I can not ask SO users to write whole project for me, it will be too much, right? That's why I thought that well known example template like Blogging will be suitable answer. I am new here, so sorry if I occcasionally do some mistakes on SO rules

Comment: That's why you break multiple issues in small questions and ask these separately and from your question it seems you need first to learn some basic programming concept before attempting to create a more complex application, like separation of view and controller (and what actually MVC is about), then you'd know why putting code/logic into the view is wrong in the first place and what controllers and actions are for and then start to learn the specifics/details about the framework/stack in question

Comment: I am learning MVC concept from docs.asp.net But I cannot ask the authors of that documentation (at least i do not know how to contact them), that is why i am asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Your best first starting place for MVC in aspnetcore is

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/index.html

If you download [visual studio community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx), the MVC project templates give you a basic structure you can start with to 'fill in the blanks'

The general answer to your question is that the linq code will most likely live in a Controller class, which will be responsible for handling the request, constructing the model (using linq like you've got), and passing it to the view (which is what you've got there).

An example controller to demonstrate:

```
[Authorize]
public class BlogsController : Controller
{
    private readonly BloggingContext _context;

    public BlogsController(BloggingContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var blogs = from x in _context.Blog select x;

        return View(blogs.ToArray());            
    }
}
```

This assumes you've got the `BlogsController` in you [projroot]\Controllers\ folder and the Index.cshtml at the [projroot]\View\Blogs\ folder.

This code returns all the blogs, since your view's @model is expecting an `IEnumerable` of `Blog`.

To get the BloggingContext injected, you'll need to add it as a service in startup.cs in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
string connectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

in appsettings.json, a node to represent that connection string, such as:

```
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "data source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=<your_db_name>;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have HomeController in my Controllers folder, but most likely you mean BlogsController in my Controllers folder(because we are talking about my view at http://localhost:18181/blogs), right? So, I put it as you suggested in BlogsController instead of return View(_context.Blog.ToList()); that was there. Then I corrected context.Blogs to context.Blog. Then i get error at BloggingContext() : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of... Potential fix is to create constructor in BloggingContext.cs - i do it. After i get error at brouser:

Comment: After it i get error at brouser: InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

Comment: Correct about the BlogsController, sorry didn't see that your view was at /blogs.  I'll update my answer.  You're blogging context will need to be injected in the constructor.  You'll need to have code in your startup.cs file to set up the service so it can be injected, I'll add a sample of that too.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have just updated my question: added Blog.cs, BlogsController.cs and BloggingContext.cs

Comment: Looking at that, it appears you're just missing the code in startup.cs to add the dbcontext so you can get it injected into your controller.

Comment: Regretfully, @Erikest , that did not work, same error as before: InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.

Comment: Hmmm...  That's strange - obviously missing something.  Try removing the empty constructor in bloggingcontext, that *might* be called by default.  Since you're not getting a null reference exception, the services container *is* injecting something there.  If the options are set up correctly in startup.cs, then the provider will be initialized in the base constructor.  So, either startup.cs isn't right, or the empty constructor in bloggingcontext is throwing things off.

Comment: If i delete the empty constructor in bloggingcontext, i get error in BlogsController.cs at: using (var context = new BloggingContext()) : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'BloggingContext.BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext>)'    I've updated question and added startup.cs    @Erikest , could you please look at it?